# Using LINQ to search between two Dates and Times

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm currently using 2 approaches in doing a search.  I run a stored proc that pulls in information between two dates.  Followed by a LINQ search within those results.

Basically the user picks a start and an end date with optional Time parameters.  For instance the user selects a start date of 01/01/2014 11am to 01/03/2014 3pm.  The problem is since the search is in 2 stages it'll search for all rows between the start and end date. Then the LINQ searches those times but then restrains it to between 11am and 3pm of each day.

For some reason I can't seem to wrap my head around how to solve this issue.  This is the code how in my app...

```
var model = db.Results(startDate, endDate)
            .Where(r => startTime == null || r.A_Time >= startTime)
            .Where(r => endTime == null || r.A_Time <= endTime)
            .OrderBy(r => r.A_Time)
            .OrderBy(r => r.A_Date)
            .Take(1000)
);
```

As requested the db structure is as follows.

```
TABLE [dbo].[TablewithInfo](
    [A_Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [A_Time] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Site] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Event] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Client] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [User] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Host] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Info] [varchar](2800) NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what it is that you want to accomplish?

Comment: And what problems are you having with your code?

Comment: What are the types of `A_Time`, `startTime` and `endTime`?

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of `OrderBy(...).OrderBy(...)` you probably want `OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)`.

Comment: You should probably combine those `Where` into one with `&&`, and use `OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)` for your ordering.

Comment: Can you not include the time in the initial SP results?  Also, what's the actual problem?

Comment: Oh! I understand now. You need to combine the date value and time value into a single DateTime object. Then use that in the query. Is the database returning string values? Or is the table split into a date column and a time column?

Comment: Sorry I should've been more specific.  @jwatts1980 is correct on what I'm attempting to do.  The date and time columns are split in the table which is what's making this a much large pain in the butt.

Comment: Can we see the DB structure?

Comment: I've updated my original post JWatts

Comment: Alexender, will you please show us your select in your sproc?  This kind of logic is best inside the routine rather than the LINQ query.

Comment: Kyle W's logic attained the goal I was going for. Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use logic like this:

```
.Where(row => startTime == null || row.A_Date > startDate || (row.A_Date == startDate && row.A_Time >= startTime))
```

So either no time specified, the date is after the current date (time doesn't matter), or it's the same date and the time is later.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me tremendously.  I just couldn't wrap my head around it.  I appreciate the help Kyle.

Comment: Damn this is really smart solution!!

Comment: I assume you would do the same line for the end date time?

Comment: @jwatts1980 It would use less-thans, but the logic would be very similar, yes.

Comment: Yeah @Abhinav I was working on some combination code myself.. but I like this better

Answer (score 1):

What the following query is doing, is redundant but necessary:

```
var sdt = CombineParameters(startDate, startTime);
var edt = CombineParameters(endDate, endTime);

var model = db.Results(startDate, endDate)
            .Where(r => (CombineParameters(r.A_Date, r.A_Time) >= sdt))
            .Where(r => (CombineParameters(r.A_Date, r.A_Time) <= edt))
            .OrderBy(r => r.A_Time)
            .OrderBy(r => r.A_Date)
            .Take(1000)
);


// Date and Time classes below are only examples, they do not exist
// Prolly you are using string ;)
private DateTime CombineParameters(Date dt, Time tt)
{
    // some way to combine dt and tt to DateTime
    // you might have to do NULL checks here etc.
}
```